# Proof that a certain subspace has infinite dimension

Tags: functional-analysis

Please help me out on this:

Prove that this is a sub-space of infinite dimension!

$$
V=\{f\in C([-1,1],{\Bbb R})\mid f(-1)=0\}\subset C([-1,1],{\Bbb R})
$$

Thanks

Comment: How comes there are so many people here who use proof as a verb? Did this really become standard?

Comment: @julien I am bewildered too. It is "How come..." also! =)

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Really? Thanks. I've only heard this expression, and never actually read it anywhere. Pointing out a language issue and starting with a mistake...That makes it my best comment so far...

Comment: @julien Hehe, but confusing a verb and a noun is way more serious!

Answer (score 3):

Hint : can you show that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a polynomial $P_n$ of degree exactly $n$ such that $P_n(-1)=0$ ? If so, you'll just have to prove that the family of the $(P_n)$ is free.

Comment: What do you mean by "free"?

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, this is a hyperplane, since it is the kernel of the linear functional $f\longmapsto f(-1)$. Now there are many ways of finding an infinite linearly independent family of functions in $V$. You've already got the polynomials. Here are two other possibilities.

1) Take $f_n(x)=\sin(n\pi(x+1))$ for $n\geq 1$.

2) Try $g_n(x)=e^{n(x+1)}-1$ for $n\geq 1$.

**Edit:** As pointed out by Glougloubarbaki, once we know $V$ is a hyperplane, it suffices to show that $C([-1,1],\mathbb{R})$ has infinite dimension. This is obvious since, for instance, it contains the polynomials which constitute an infinite-dimensional subspace on an infinite set like $[-1,1]$.

Comment: I think that showing those families are linearly independent is almost as hard as solving the exercise... Also I guess you could say that since it is the kernel of a non-zero linear form, it is a hyperplane and must be of infinite dimension if it is known that $C(-1,1)$ has infinite dimension

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki True. I'll add that. Note that there is a big difference between having no idea where to start, and checking that a given family is linearly independent. Thanks for your input, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this by proving that for every n > 0 there exists a set of n independent vectors f1,...,fn.

Take for instance fk the function that maps -1 + 2*k/n to 1, and is 0 elsewhere, except in the intervals [-1 + 2*(k-1)/n,-1 + 2*k/n] and [-1 + 2*k/n,-1 + 2*(k+1)/n] where it progresses linearly from 0 to 1 (resp. from 1 to 0).

The functions thus constructed are continuous and are independent since for each k, exactly one of them differs from 0 in the point -1 + 2*k/n.